# TypeError: reduce() of empty sequence with no initial value when merging

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframes which look like this:

df1

```
Value    Hectares_2006
1        10
5        15
```

df2

```
Value   Hectares_2007
1       20
5       5
```

df3

```
Value  Hectares_2008
1      22
5      3
```

and I want to merge them all together by first putting all of the dataframes in a list and then using:

`dfs = reduce(lambda left, right: pd.merge(left, right, on=['Value'], how='outer'), list1`)

but this returns:

```
 File "E:/python codes/temp.py", line 32, in <module>
    dfs=reduce(lambda left, right: pd.merge(left, right, on=['VALUE'], how='outer'), list1)

TypeError: reduce() of empty sequence with no initial value
```

my desired output is:

```
Value  Hectares_2006   Hectares_2007   Hectares_2008
1      10              20              22
5      15              5               3
```

my full code is this, with `files` pathway the pathway to all my files which become the dataframes:

```
import pandas as pd, os
from simpldbf import Dbf5

list1=[]
files=r'E:\Documents\2015 Summer RA\CDL_in_buffer'
for f in os.listdir(files):
    if '.dbf' in f and '.xml' not in f:
        table=Dbf5(os.path.join(files,f))
        df=table.to_dataframe()
        columns=['VALUE', 'CLASS_NAME','Count']
        df=df[columns]
        if ('2006' in f) or ('2007' in f) or ('2008' in f) or ('2009' in f):
            df['Hectares']=df.Count*0.3136
        if ('2010' in f) or ('2011' in f) or ('2012' in f) or ('2013' in f) or ('2014' in f) or ('2015' in f):
            df['Hectares']=df.Count*0.09
        df.drop(['Count'], axis=1, inplace=True)
        df=df[df['CLASS_NAME'] .isin (['Corn'])]
        df.rename(columns={'CLASS_NAME': 'Crop_' + f.split('.')[0], 'Hectares': 'Hectares_' + f.split('.')[0] }, inplace=True)
        list1.append(df)
    dfs=reduce(lambda left, right: pd.merge(left, right, on=['VALUE'], how='outer'), list1)
```

Comment: What's `list1`?

Comment: the list I put all the dataframes in, `list1=[]` then `list1.append(df)` while in a loop

Comment: Can you verify that `list1` isn't empty? From the error message it sounds like it's empty. Maybe put an `assert(list1)` before the line that's throwing the error.

Comment: when I print `list1` it prints as expected

Comment: Oh, I see the problem. You should un-indent the `dfs=...` line so it's outside of the for loop.

Comment: ahhh, yep, so simple, if you want to add as an answer I will accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you need to un-indent the `dfs=...` line so that it's outside of the for loop. Otherwise, `list1` will be empty on the first iteration of the loop if the first file seen doesn't contain `.dbf`, which will cause the empty sequence error.